# Passing Vector by Reference- Segmentation Fault C++

Tags: c++, vector, reference, segmentation-fault

I've looked up passing vectors by reference, and it seems like what I'm doing should work. I tested this with only assigning 1 value into the vector and I was still getting segmentation faults. Any help or ideas why this is happening would be much appreciated.

**Pseudo code:**

```
    template <class X>
    void class<X>::function(const X &A, const X &B, vector<X>&results) const {

         int temp = A;
         int i = 0;

         while (temp > B){
               if(another_function(temp)){
                    results[i] = temp;
                    i++;
               }
         }
    }
```

Basically, A will always be larger than B so the while loop occurs every time. The "another_function" takes an int value, returns true if certain conditions are met, and decreases its value every time. I tested it where it would only store 3 elements in the vector, and still got segmentation fault (core dumped) error...

**Edit:** I also commented out `results[i] = temp;` and it worked fine.

Comment: How do you know you're not writing off the end of results? There is no check that i < results.size().

Comment: How do you pass temp to another_function()? By reference or by value? Hopefully, by reference, but please confirm.

Comment: Well i figured I guess just trying it with 3 elements wouldn't get anywhere near the size of... I added the check and I no longer get segmentation fault, but no elements were stored in results... ah.... does the size of the vector change since it's templated?

Comment: `results.push_back(temp);`

Comment: and yes @Oleg, it is also passed by reference. I no longer get seg fault, but no elements are stored. testing it with all templates as ints for consistency

Comment: Got it working. Guess my whole use of i and i++ was giving it issues. push_back() worked great. Thank you all.

Comment: @Laurim: You can try results.at(i) to check that your program is accessing  the out of index error or not. In this situation you would get standard exception and hence you can understand your logic. Moreover it could be heap corruption somewhere else in your program which is leading into this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing vectors by references works. It's a fact :)
What does not work in your case is that you fail to guarantee that you don't index past the end of the vector.
Your code must guarantee that every time you do

```
results[i] = temp;
```

, i is always less than results.size().

Comment: Thank you. That got rid of the segmentation fault, and push_back() made it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have reserved enough capacity for the `vector`, you should use `push_back`.

Replace the line

```
results[i] = temp;
```

by

```
results.push_back(temp);
```